Took a pic of old school friend in the 80s who is now quite famous and written a huge selling memoir. Pic has ben used in book without permission
The book was published back in 2017. It is a true story.
When I purchased it, I realised they had used a photo from 1982 that I had taken of them when we were kids.
The book has now been made into 2 TV mini series. I am not really sure how to go about this.
I have the original photo in my possession. Is this copyright even though the picture is of him. Any help would be appreciated.

What is your region, because law and copyright differ from country to country?

"I am not really sure how to go about this." How to go about what, exactly? What do you wish to accomplish? For them to stop using your photo? (for future possible usage) To get paid? (not likely since it's been more than 2 years since the infringement occurred and you have not already sued within that two year period) Something else?

@MichaelC where did the two year thing come from?

Generally speaking, the photographer owns the photo, regardless of who is depicted. But if the photo was taken in 1982, and it is in your possession, then how did it come to be published in the book? How did the book publisher get ahold of the photo?

Mod note: I'm leaving this open. The core question of "who owns the copyright of a photo person X took of person Y" is, while a legal question, well within the scope of our site and doesn't need country-specific info to answer.

@osullic, section 507(b) of the US copyright law...except it is 3 years.

@PhilipKendall, it does need country-specific info: before March 1, 1989, the United States had substantially different copyright laws from the rest of the world.

@Mark that's a fair point; I forgot the US wasn't a signatory to the Berne Convention before then.

I took thousands of pictures of my school friends back in 1980s... I never implied anything other than "do whatever you want with your picture". Some of these pictures later ended up in Facebook and likes. Should I worry? I don't think so.

@Antares Having the right to demand deletion is not the same as owning copyright. If I, as a photographer, take a portrait of a friend of mine, that does not give that friend the right to reproduce, exhibit or sell the photo without my permission.

@Antares; you are mixing privacy rights with copyrights... different laws with different applications. The right to erasure is more about database storage/privacy information and not an otherwise authorized/legal use of an image. As for "right of likeness" (also a privacy right), you have to be much more specific as to which country...

@StevenKersting Not only about which country, but about the specific circumstances under which the photo was taken. Public area? Private area? Posed (with implied permission to take the photo)? Not posed/candid (esp. in a non-public setting)?

Legal options depend on the country's laws
As with any real legal advice from a non-lawyer, anything you hear here or on any other internet site is to be taken with a grain of salt. Please seek out a lawyer for this case.
Also know that copyright laws differ from country to country, so that without more specifics, no one can give you any advice.
What do you want to achieve?
As Michael already pointed out, what is your intention?
Do you want them to cease using your image in future? There is a good chance even a stern letter to the publisher would achieve that.
Do you want to get financial compensation? You might be able to get a small license fee out of it. As the image is most probably not a major part of the book, I would not expect too much from that.
Do you want them to destroy all current unsold versions of the book? This would be the nuclear option — and I think it requires a very special and hostile mindset to aim for that. Also, you are very unlikely to find a legal basis.
Do you want to have the images credited to you? This also might just be done with a friendly letter and asking for credit in future.
Can you prove your ownership?
This usually means: do you own the negatives of the image? If the other side is uncooperative, you will have to give proof of your claims.
What would I propose?
Write them a nice letter asking for credit in future editions. There are no riches to be collected, I think. And the lawyer you would need would probably cost more than you would get back in return.

There is no legal position for any demand/finding  here (in the US). No cease/desist, no compensation, no credit line; nothing... In some countries there may be the right to credit under moral rights clauses, but in the US that right only applies to examples of fine art. The only thing that could/would be awarded is rights in any future use. E.g. if a third book was made using the picture (those rights already exists), or if one of the previous books was reissued (i.e. credit line added, picture eliminated, etc).

@StevenKersting Any books already printed would be clear. Any future printings could be affected by a cease and desist order. In today's publishing environment, where many books are printed on demand, it could very well be that the OP could prevent future use of the photo in additional copies of the first book.

@MichaelC, I hadn't really considered e-book/print on demand... that would be one for a court to figure out, but I'm pretty sure there's no money in that market and it's probably not the concern here. I'm also sure that a credit line for an old snapshot isn't worth anything...

No money, but maybe an enforceable cease and desist.

Yes, it is a copyright issue even though the picture is of the other individual. Copyright belongs to the author, not the subject.
In the US there is a three-year time limitation for filing an infringement claim. It has been well beyond three years since you first knew about the infringement (or should have known), so you have no case. Legally, you gave an unlimited "implied license" by not objecting, and you cannot change your mind now that you think there might be some money in it. You still own copyright in relation to any other/future use, but you have no position for complaint/demand in this instance…
Other countries have similar limitations for the same reason (6 yrs UK, 5 yrs FR, 3 yrs CA). To get the most informed advice, you should talk to an IP lawyer (not just any lawyer).

It seems at least a bit complicated in the USA though. In Warner Chappell Music, Inc. v. Nealy, the SCOTUS ruled that damages are not limited by the 3 year rule, if the case was brought within the 3 year discovery/reasonable discovery window. That case didn't clarify what "reasonably should have discovered" means (and I'm not sure you want to be the SCOTUS case that does)

@Kaia, yes that ruling said damages could go back farther than three years if there was a valid reason for a delay in discovery; in that case it was imprisonment. The discovery window is generally based upon the last date of being made readily available for discovery, or publishing (which used to require a copyright notice be added)... this is also called the "injury rule." Without extenuating circumstances, the "injury rule" and the "discovery rule" are coincident. But again, an IP lawyer would be your best resource...

The notion that copyright ownership of a casual snapshot belongs to the photographer, if actually enforced, would mean that many if not most casual snapshots of people would be orphaned copyright works.  If someone were to ask me for copyright permission for a casual snapshot I took of them but have no particular memory of, I may be willing to sign a document waiving any copyright interest I might have in the photo, but if I have no particular memory of having taken the picture I couldn't grant copyright permission to something I may or may not own.

@supercat That notion is the law; the law makes no distinction between casual snapshots and any other photographs. For one example, the casual filming of JFK became the Zapruder film. Even if JFK hadn't been shot, that still would have been copyrighted by Zapruder, even if it had been passed through several hands and been recovered with no labels of the original author. It's problematic, but it is how copyright law works.

@supercat, just because you own the copyrights does not mean you need to enforce them; e.g. the implied license. Similarly, you can grant license w/o contract/verbally (in the US); "here you go"... as long as you stand behind that verbal agreement. But the issue should be obvious; does "here you go" mean copyright transfer, full release/license, or limited/personal? That would be up to a judge to decide because it's not in writing/clear; and that gets messy/expensive.

@StevenKersting: If someone hands someone a camera and asks them to take their picture, and the person accepts the camera, takes a picture, and hands it back, saying that the second person would own the copyright in the absence of a written waiver, and could enforce it at any desired future time, would severely limit what could ever be done with the picture, especially since the camera owner would often have no way of identifying the "copyright holder" or knowing whether the copyright holder might later claim adverse ownership (if e.g. the person who took the photo later saw it in print...

I don't see how you can establish the "should have known." No reasonable person goes out and checks all books published to see if someone might have used a photo they took. You often see content that was published for over 3 years taken down. I do understand that compensation is limited by such a rule, but financial compensation isn't the only remedy being proposed here.

...and demanded damages, there may not be any evidence that he was the photographer if the camera owner claimed not to remember, but if the camera owner is honest and is unwilling to lie, that shouldn't put the camera on the hook for thousands of dollars damages.

@supercat: That is another question: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/130405/copyright-when-i-ask-a-stranger-to-take-a-photo-of-me-in-front-of-a-landmark

Have you tried talking to your old friend and telling him what you want to do about this situation? If he's an honourable individual, he might very well do what you want - whatever that is - simply because he's become aware of the situation and wants to do the right thing.
I know of one incident that is somewhat similar where that appears to have happened. During the recording of Dark Side of the Moon, Pink Floyd hired a woman named Claire Torry to sing an improvised vocal on a song called The Great Gig in the Sky. Originally, only members of Pink Floyd were credited for the composition of the song but many years later, the credit was changed so that Torry was also credited with the song. (I assume she began receiving royalties for it due to the song-writing credit but I don't know that for a fact.) Now, I don't know if she simply contacted them and complained that she thought she was owed a credit or if she had to take legal action but it's possible she just asked them nicely and they saw her point and gave her the credit. (It was, after all, a brilliant performance and they had not given her much direction about the content of the performance so they couldn't really claim much in the way of creative input to the performance.)
If you reach out to your old friend - or "his people" if he's famous now - and identify yourself and what you want to do about the picture, he might just surprise you and do what you want willingly without having to involve lawyers.

The most you can expect is an acknowledgement.  Unless you do NOT want the photo used, in which case, having it pulled is clearly the aim.
If it were me, I wouldn't bother.  Because its going to cost you a couple of grand in legal fees just to send the relevant letters.
And btw if the photo was accessible online via fb or something - the IP is gone.   You've got nothing to fight for, other than bragging rights
Is photography a serious hobby or profession for you?
If not, don't give it another moment's thought.  You won't get financial compensation; you WILL just create a  huge headache for yourself, the artist ... Pick your battles :)

"And btw if the photo was accessible online via fb or something - the IP is gone." This is completely incorrect; you do not give up rights to your IP by posting something online.

@PhilipKendall Realistically speaking, IP law is basically unenforceable once it's been posted online, considering that there are servers located in countries beyond the reach of the Berne Convention.

@MichaelC probably enforceable against the specific publisher of the book in question though.

@PhilipKendall Only going forward. Anything published that has passed the statute of limitations is normally not retroactively enforceable.

Don't get antsy about it. Just be honoured that you took an image that was deemed good enough to be included in the long list of things that make a book worthy of publication. That honour is the only thing you can take with you when you go. No pockets in a shroud. Revel in your moment of self-gratification. A shutter click, however well-aimed, is never going to equate the two-three years it takes to write a halfway decent novel, never mind the chance of publication being equivalent to a lightning strike or all the numbers in the Lottery. Wish them well. Buy the book, watch the box set and feel good to have contributed. Forget trying to enrich lawyers. They already have enough.
